# Resolved color instead of a resource id

Tags: android, lint

Recently I've seen appeared a lint error in my code:

> Should pass resolved color instead of resource id here:
>   getResources().getColor(R.color.maps_list_background_color)
>   MyClass.java  /myapp/android/maps line 107    Android Lint Problem

I know how to resolve it the answer is in the error, the thing is I don't get why they have added this error in the linter.

Comment: Is `maps_list_background_color` a color thats declared in Strings.xml?

Comment: No it's a color that I've defined in res/values/colors.xml

Answer (score 60, accepted):

> Methods that take a color in the form of an integer should be passed an RGB triple, not the actual color resource id. You must call getResources.getColor(resource).

The function you are calling is expecting an integer that is an RGB triple, not just the id of a color resource. The color resource id is still an integer, but would not produce the color that you are expecting if it was used as the RGB triple. In order to pass it the correct RGB triple for your color, you must resolve it with the `getResources().getColor(R.color.example_color)` call.

Comment: This lint error seems to show even for user-created methods that have the word 'color' in them. I thought that adding `@ColorRes` to the `int` paramater would remove this error, but it did not.

Comment: @JasonRobinson more specifically, if your method ends with the word `color`. I just made my method named `setButtonColorInt` and warning went away.

Comment: you might need to add 'ContextName'.getResources().getColor(..)

Answer (score 60):

Since I'm still finding this on Google and it is deprecated, I thought I'd might as well share the current method of doing this.

check [getResources().getColor() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842983/getresources-getcolor-is-deprecated)

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.color_name)
```

Comment: in my case ContexCompat has no getColor method

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context, int) it does. Also not sure if you copy pasted from your code, because there is a typo in ContextCompat (missing t)

Comment: AWESOMEEEEE, thanks a lot this also handles the hassle of api<17 when using getResources().getColor(id,theme)
thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

Since `getResources().getColor()` is deprecated, you need to do this to get the color:

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),your_color_id);
```

Now you have the color with respect to the current context
Set the color using:

```
your_view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Answer (score 7):

Use annotation `@ColorInt` to confirm that this is color not a color reference id.

See: 
[android.support.annotation.ColorInt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/ColorInt.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for (the warning seems ok, but this is an elegant way to disable it if you know what you're doing...)

Answer (score 4):

As for me, it's very stupid warning.

I have own class with function:

```
public static final void setBackgroundColor(View v, int id) {
// Here I get color by id from resources and setBackgroundColor of this color.
}
```

Anyway, if I try call `setBackgroundColor`, I get warning. But why?

So, I did simple: rename `setBackgroundColor` to `setBackgroundColorr`.

This warning activate if found name `color` at function name.

And yes, I do not like name setColorBackground or any other :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using androidx, you can do:

```
requireContext().getColor(R.color.myColor);
```

Answer (score -2):

Apparently this is caused by lint; third bullet down.

[New Lint Rules](http://tools.android.com/recent/newlintrules-1)

You could probably surpress this, or try implementing their syntax.

Comment: Yep but it still doesn't explain why they have added this rule in the linter and how they detect that this int is a resource id instead of a color

Comment: From the accepted answer, it seems like suppressing this would be a bad idea.