# getResources().getColor() is deprecated

Tags: android, deprecated, android-resources, android-color

Using: 
`buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"` , 
`targetSdkVersion 22` in my gradle file.

I found that the useful `getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name)` is deprecated.

What should I use instead?

Comment: Where do you see that? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)

Comment: This has been discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31590714/getcolorint-id-deprecated-on-android-mnc-preview-2

Comment: Use ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)

Comment: in Adapter context.getResources().

Comment: ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorname)

For Fragments it would be "activity as Context" and for activities it will be "this"

Answer (score 1264, accepted):

It looks like the best approach is to use:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)
```

eg:

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext,
                            R.color.colorAccent))
```

This will choose the Marshmallow two parameter method or the pre-Marshmallow method appropriately.

Comment: Kotlin: replace 'applicationContext' with 'this'

Comment: to use in Kotlin as Ben Said                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                     ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color_name)

Comment: What if you have an instance of "Resources" and not of "Context"?

Answer (score 74):

well it's deprecated in android M so you must make exception for android M and lower. Just add current theme on `getColor` function. You can get current theme with `getTheme()`.

This will do the trick in fragment, you can replace `getActivity()` with `getBaseContext()`, `yourContext`, etc which hold your current context

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    yourTitle.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white, getActivity().getTheme()));
}else {
    yourTitle.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
}
```

*p.s : color is deprecated in M, but drawable is deprecated in L

Comment: Instead of `getActivity().getTheme()`, I'd use `getContext().getTheme()`

Comment: Its very usefull.Its working for me

Answer (score 49):

You need to use ContextCompat.getColor(), which is part of the Support V4 Library (so it will work for all the previous API).

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)
```

As specified in the documentation, "Starting in M, the returned color will be styled for the specified Context's theme". SO no need to worry about it.

You can add the Support V4 library by adding the following to the dependencies array inside your app build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

Comment: What if you have an instance of "Resources" and not of "Context"?

Answer (score 26):

> I found that the useful getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name) is deprecated.

It is not deprecated in API Level 21, according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29).

It *is* deprecated in the M Developer Preview. However, the replacement method (a two-parameter `getColor()` that takes the color resource ID and a `Resources.Theme` object) is only available in the M Developer Preview.

Hence, right now, continue using the single-parameter `getColor()` method. Later this year, consider using the two-parameter `getColor()` method on Android M devices, falling back to the deprecated single-parameter `getColor()` method on older devices.

Comment: Why did Android's developers not just keep the method which can internally select from a default option, and provide the second overloaded method for those that need it. Google need to stop foisting their own developer concerns on the masses. It's needless change and over complication.