# How to get Background Shape color of buttons?

Tags: android, button, colors, drawable, background-color

I have 9 custom round buttons each  when clicked opens the color picker and a save button  at  bottom view  retrieves all the data .

My problem is  i am not able to retrieve the color correctly.and also the code can retrieve the data above 24 version .that is also useless.
[image: Debugger output]
**Sample code**

This code is invoked everytime the button is click .it gets the color value from  color picker.

```
GradientDrawable c1, c2;
  Button mcbt_1,mcbt_2;

           // this function gets call everytime button is clicked ,it sets the color to the background and maintain the shape of button to circle.
            public void onColorSelected(int color) {
                switch (buttonSelected) {
                    case 1:
                        c1 = (GradientDrawable) Mcbt_1.getBackground();
                        c1.setColor(color);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        c2 = (GradientDrawable) Mcbt_2.getBackground();
                        c2.setColor(color);
                        break;

                }
            }
```

This code gets the background color of the  buttons present in the view.But major issue is version support. and also data i am getting is last color value of button. for example: if int color1 = (-15210) for button 1 and int color2 =(-15700) then when i get  the value using  this

```
   c1 = (GradientDrawable) Mcbt_1.getBackground();
                            color_BT_1 = c1.getColor().getDefaultColor();
```

from the above code i get color_BT_1 as  -15700 and color_BT_2 as -15700.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        c1 = (GradientDrawable) Mcbt_1.getBackground();
                        color_BT_1 = c1.getColor().getDefaultColor();

                        c2 = (GradientDrawable) Mcbt_2.getBackground();
                        color_BT_2 = c2.getColor().getDefaultColor();

                       String edColor = color_BT_1 + "," + color_BT_2 ;
}
```

Comment: well it appears you `mcbt_4` doesnt have a background , as it was null.

Comment: Hello @AbdulKawee i have not run the entire debugger . the value of mcbt_4 also is same as mcbt_1,2,3 and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To getColor of Background Below API 24, you have to use ColorDrawable. The documentation for the same can be found over [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) docmentation and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842983/getresources-getcolor-is-deprecated) answer as well.

The problem was in saving the values of the color rather than getting it.

I hope this helps.