# How to change button background for TargetSDK 23 which works in TargetSDK 21 perfectly?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have one project which is running perfectly for TargetSDK Version 21 but when I Switch to the Version 23 some weird error occur during Changing the Background Color of Dynamic Button.

- [Example, below screenshot Refer to the version 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BpzQ.jpg)
- [Example, below screenshot Refer to the version 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5AiV.jpg)

  ```
      textArray[selection].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
              R.color.blue));
      textArray[selection].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
  ```

I am Using these two lines to change background color and textcolor for button.

Note:- Both times the Code to set Backgroundcolor is same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: whatever you tried so far for setting bg color

Comment: Please try to get color using `ContextCompat` like this. `textArray[selection].setBackgroundColor( ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue));` . It may help you. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842983/getresources-getcolor-is-deprecated

Comment: @pRaNaY Background color gets Changed but textcolor of button is not Changed it seems like textcolor does not change

Comment: One of your buttons (the upper left ) is colored properly. Does this mean that the problem is focused on the right side buttons?

Comment: @mTak it is selected by default when the clicked of the other buttons the same set on code runs but it does not work for them on Click of Button

Comment: Are all the buttons enabled?

Comment: @mTak yes all are enable

Comment: share more code to understand what you're doing

Comment: @mTak brother i am not doing anything another than what i had shared i write only two lines of code to change color..Currently i am on targetSDk 23 if i switch to 22 it's started working Properly.