# MainActivity.java: uses or overrides a deprecated API. Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java, android-studio

I have no clue how to solve this issue.
When I try to compile the folder to APK file, there is message that says

> MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

I am using Android Studio version 3.2.0 and Java version 8. I tried everything but it doesn't work. I also searched up internet but I couldn't get the answer.

```
package com.kakao.talk.theme.apeach;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final String KAKAOTALK_SETTINGS_THEME_URI = 
"kakaotalk://settings/theme/";
private static final String MARKET_URI = "market://details?id=";
private static final String KAKAO_TALK_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.kakao.talk";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        try {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statusBarColor));
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        try {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }
    }

    final Button applyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply);
    applyButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(KAKAOTALK_SETTINGS_THEME_URI + getPackageName()));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    final Button installButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.market);
    installButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(MARKET_URI + KAKAO_TALK_PACKAGE_NAME));
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    try {
        getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(KAKAO_TALK_PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
        applyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        installButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        applyButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        installButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi usser1222, welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that APKs (should) still be compiled even if you get that log. (It should be a warning) Could you also try passing the `-Xlint:deprecation` flag to your Gradle command?

Comment: I changed your tagging for you, N.B. Java and JavaScript are two very, very different things.

Comment: I ignored it and tried to download it onto my phone, but it does not work (for some reason...)
What do you mean by "passing the Xlint:deprecation flag to Gradle command"? 
I am so sorry :( I am new to this whole stuff and I am lost

*BTW thank you so much for changing the tag!

Answer (score 2):

welcome to StackOverflow!

In your code, after the version check, you are trying to set the window status color by using `getResources().getColor()`, which has been deprecated for a few years now.

You can use the [ContextCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat) to achieve this: `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)`.

You should change `R.color.color_name` for your desired resource (in your case should be `R.color.statusBarColor`) as well as pass the correct context (which should be `getApplicationContext()`).

Further information can be found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842983/getresources-getcolor-is-deprecated), and never forget the [great google's documentation on Android](https://developers.google.com/android/).

Comment: When I replaced getResources().getColor() with ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name), I have errors reporting that they cannot find symbol variable color_name, etc... What should I do?

Comment: The part "R.color.statusBarColor" worked like a charm, but "ContextCompat" and "getTargetContext()" does not work :(
I am using 3.2.0 version of Android Studio.. Should I download the newest version just in case this one is outdated?

Comment: No. It should work on 3.2.0.
Are you importing the ContextCompat correctly?

Comment: Your line should end-up on something like this: window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getApplicationContext(), R.color.statusBarColor)

Comment: When I replace it with ContextCompat, it says "Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? If this answer is what you were looking for, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: It's not working :( Do you happen to know the reason why it says "Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details." when I replaced the wording to ContextCompat?

Comment: You need to check on the console for further information regarding the error.

Comment: How should I check the console? I am so sorry :( I am new to this whole system and I have no clue how to solve these issues..

Comment: I'm really sorry for being a little rude. But those other questions that surged, initially are not related to the question itself. The provided answer was tested and does work with different Android API levels, for further stuff regarding how the IDE works or other silly development doubts, per example, please refer to google or other stack overflow questions.