# getColor(int id) deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio

I solved it like this, do you think it is correct?

```
getColor(int id, Theme theme);
getColor(R.color.green, getContext().getTheme());
```

Where "green" is in `res/colors.xml`:

```
<color name="green">#FF00FF00</color>
```

Comment: This solution is fine, let's say you switch theme to darkmode and your green color is defined #fff in the dark theme styling it would automatically switch.

Answer (score 7):

Use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)`
As this answer shows: [getResources().getColor() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842983/getresources-getcolor-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Just use 2 Steps below.

1. Import this dependecy in Activity

   ```
       ->  import android.graphics.Color
   ```
2. For Statusbar write the code in the onCreate() method.

   ```
       ->   // Set Background Transparent of Status bar
            window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
   ```
3. For Bottom button Navigationbar write the code in the onCreate() method.

   ```
       ->   // Set Background Transparent of bottomNavigation
            window.navigationBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
   ```