# Programatically change background color of widgets in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change the background color of items in my RecyclerView programmatically by if else conditions. I followed the answer of this questions, but it does not work anymore.
[getResources().getColor() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842983/getresources-getcolor-is-deprecated)

Here is my code in the adapter class:

```kotlin
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotificationsViewHolder, position: Int)
        {
            holder.title.text = notifications[position].title
            holder.description.text = notifications[position].description
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orangeLight))
        }
```

This code does not work because it requires a support library that is no longer supported. Instead AndroidX with Jetpack is suggested by Google.
I do not want to use Jetpack since I am using Kotlin.
Is there a way to programmatically change background color of widgets using Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would edit your ViewHolder class like this:

```kotlin
    class NotificationsViewHolder(itemView: View, var context: Context): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val res = context.resources
        val colorName = "orangeLight"
        val colorResId = res.getIdentifier(colorName, "color", context.packageName)
        val colorHexCode = res.getColor(colorResId)

    }
```

Then inside `onBindViewHolder()` method you can set background like this:

```kotlin
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotificationsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(holder.colorHexCode)
    }
```