# Unable to set color for BarChart in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to set a specific color for a bar in `BarChart` from `MPAndroidChart`. I do everything according to a documentation, but the color isn't changing.
Here's my code:

```
   barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.bar_chart);
   List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
   entries.add(new BarEntry(1.0f, 10.0f)); //tmp values

   BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "bars");
   dataSet.setColor(R.color.red); //color from resourses

   BarData barData = new BarData(dataSet);

   barChart.setData(barData);
   barChart.invalidate();
```

The funny thing is that before I tried to change the color of the bar, the bar was blue, after I tried to change its color, it became grey (no matter, what color it must be). I don't understand why doesn't the color change.
I also tried to override `getColor` method in the `BarDataSet` class, but result is the same -- bar is grey.

[image: Grey, but not red]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change this line,

```
dataSet.setColor(R.color.red); //resource id of a color
```

to,

```
dataSet.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)); //resolved color
```

When you call `setColor` you need to pass in an integer that represents an RGB triple. `R.color.red` is not an RGB triple but instead an integer that represents a resource in `R.java`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989319/resolved-color-instead-of-a-resource-id) for more about the difference between a resource id and a resolved color.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly, but why should I write in this way? What was not correct in my code? And, moreover, Android Studio says, that 'getColor' method is deprecated. What should I use instead of it?

Comment: I found out, that I should use `ContextCompat.getColor()` instead of deprecated `getResourses().getColor()`, but first quistion still remains.

Answer (score 2):

```
  BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "bars");
   dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set color, you can create and array of color. Then set that array to Bardataset.
Example is given Below.

```
int[] colors = {Color.rgb(153, 193, 12), Color.rgb(179, 130, 76)};

    Bardataset.setColors(colors);
```

I think you should write Your code in this sequence.
Take a look below :

```
      BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(entries, "bars");
      dataSet.setColor(Color.parseColor("#104E78"));
      BarData barData = new BarData(dataSet);
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

We can change color this way.

```
    bardataset.setColors(new int[]{getResources().getColor(R.color.red)});
```