# MPAndroidChart Custom Legend Icons are Grey

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using a LineChart from MPAndroidChart and I want to implement a custom legend.
When I add a label and a corresponding LegendForm with a spezific color, the chart displays the form in grey anyway.

How can I give the form the color I want?

Here is the code I use:

```
LegendEntry("testTest", Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE, Float.NaN, Float.NaN , null , R.color.blue)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are passing as a parameter a color resource id (`ColorRes`) where you actually need a resolved color (an RGB triple or `@ColorInt`).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738955/5241933) for the difference between them; in short they are both integers but one of them is an id that points to a resource like `R.color.blue` and another is an `int` that represents an RGB triple like `#0000FF`.

You should change your code to:

```
new LegendEntry("testTest", Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE, Float.NaN, Float.NaN , null , ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.blue, null));
```